# What is a good multiplatform vector graphics library for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, vector-graphics

I'm looking for a good multiplatform library for vector graphics in C/C++. Any recommendation or thougts?

Thanks

EDIT: Thanks for all your answers!! Could anyone tell me the pros and cons of qt vs cairo, for example? Cairo got more votes, but it seems to be from 5 to 7 times slower according to some benchmarks...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try out [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/) - it's opensource, not too heavy and has a flexible license.

Answer (score 10):

I like Nokia's [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/). Not only vector graphics but also high level widgets.

Answer (score 9):

There is [Anti-Grain Geometry](http://www.antigrain.com/).

Answer (score 2):

How about ImageMagick, or OpenCV (Computer vision) though! They are both good for basic graphics, and OpenCV can do magic when it comes to Computer Vision.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display DXF/DWG and the like, use CadImage.DLL from www.CadSoftTools.com. Its commercial, Windows only, written in Delphi (has a C-Inteface). 
We tried several Libs with huge (>100MB) DXF-Files. This is the only one that didn't break down and its the fastest one. Godd support as well. Company in Russia.

Comment: That's very interesting indeed. Actually I'm looking for multiplatform, and that's very important, but thanks for your answer

Comment: If you're after multiplatform support for DWG & DXF try the Open Design Alliance at http://www.opendesign.com/.